# Enable autocomplete feature in aurelia single page application

Tags: single-page-application, aurelia

We have enabled autocomplete property true for all input fields. We didn't use form tags in the templates. The input fields don't fetch the previously entered data. So how can we implement autocomplete property.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this is not specific to Aurelia. Once the element is in the DOM, it is a feature of the browser to offer the user a previously entered value for that field given that an assumption can be made about what the field is supposed to be!).

Depending on the browser, the autofill feature relies on having 'known' input attributes (name and type) and possibly even the surrounding text, including label text.

If you are not getting the expected results, try making sure your inputs have very obvious name attributes, first. Eg.

```
<input type="text" name="email">
```

If you could share a snippet of code, I might be able to offer more help.